# How do I make a window draggable without a header?

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3, pygtk

So basically I have this main window with just a bunch of buttons on it. I am hiding the default header by using **self.set_decorated(False)**. I want to be able to drag the window around my screen by clicking anywhere that's not a button. Is this possible? I haven't been able to find anything on this except for self.begin_move_drag(self.button_drag, event.x_root, event.y_root, event.time) which I don't really understand.

Comment: Try holding <ALT> on your keyboard, then dragging anywhere on the window.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, any idea why?

Comment: <ALT> is a hotkey for the window manager. Since I use Cinnamon, it is already configured that <ALT> makes a window draggable anywhere, not just on the titlebar. You may need to set the hotkey for your window manager.

Comment: Thank you this works, but it's not quite what I was looking for. Is it possible to do it without holding a hotkey? Another alternative I could do is have a HeaderBar, but the problem with that is that the default length is too long and I can't find a way to shrink it (which is why I even posted in the first place) if that makes sense.

Comment: Or if I could somehow make the HeaderBar vertical, that could work too.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it! I did hb.props.custom_title = Gtk.Label(label=" ") Which does what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hb.props.custom_title = Gtk.Label(label=" ")